# Increase the font size and height of Title field of the tab panel

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

```
Ext.define('ProjectExample.view.example' ,{
    extend:'Ext.tab.Panel',
    title:'TITLE BAR',
    layout:'fit',
    ....
```

This is my `Tab Panel` Application, i need to Increase the text size of the `title` attribute, and increase the height of it. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from CSS. check the Div id for tab panel and re size the title font-size.

Comment: Could you give me a link, where i could refer it ?

Comment: And, if i make a change to that DIV tag, will it effect all title bars in the application ? I only need to increase the height of a title bar in a particular screen.